# What does it mean myFunction is not a function?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm passing storyLike function from parent to child.Sometimes when onPress is clicked I get following error:           this.props.storyLike(props.story) is not a function.
I thought it's a context issue but couldn't resolve it.

[image]

Here is my Parent:

```
renderRow(item) {
        return (
          <Story
            story={item}
            openStory={this.props.openStory}
            getProfile={this.props.getProfile}
            storyLike={this.props.storyLike}
          />
        );
      }
```

Here is child component Story, just passing props to StoryFooter component:

```
class Story extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <StoryHeader {...this.props} />
        <StoryContent {...this.props} />
        <StoryFooter {...this.props} storyViewType={"feed"} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Bellow is child component, I'm triggering storyLike from onPress changeLikedStatus function:

```
class StoryFooter extends Component {
  state = { isLiked: false, likes: 0 };

  changeLikedState(props) {
    const numberOflikes = this.state.isLiked
      ? this.state.likes - 1
      : this.state.likes + 1;

    if (this.state.isLiked) {
      this.setState({ isLiked: false, likes: numberOflikes });
    } else {
      this.setState({ isLiked: true, likes: numberOflikes });
    }
      this.props.storyLike(props.story);
  }

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.changeLikedState(this.props)}>
```

Comment: Show how Parent is getting this.props.storyLike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your parent should look like

```
  renderRow(item) {
            return (
              <Story
                // ... other props
                storyLike={(prop) => this.props.storyLike(prop)}
              />
            );
          }
```

This way you explicitly tell that the child will be passing a prop to the function.

Hopefully your `storyLike` function is an arrow function that looks like this:

```
storyLike = (prop) => {
    // code
}
```

Comment: @J.range does the declaration of your storyLike function looks like a typed it above?

Comment: this.props.storyLike(props.story); here is declaration @eduard

Comment: this is not a declaration, this is an invokement. The declaration should either look like I have shown in above in my answer or like this or be a regular function declaration like: storyLike(prop) { //code}

Comment: I have not declare it anywhere, im just passing it as prop.Should I declare it in parent component and just pass it bellow to child?

Comment: you need to declare a function in order to invoke it